# Make button within the list the same height as list elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am testing a simple layout consisting of list items where I would like to make the last li a button and the same height as previous ones.

here is a simple code

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li> <!--This one should be a button-->
</ul>
```

here is [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fr6gachf/)

I am trying to avoid script unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: You can set a fixed height on `li` elements in CSS OR calculate and set a height with a script, I think a script is needed here.

Comment: yes I am out of options and would probably need to calculate height with a script and pass it to the button since everything is responsive

Answer (score 0):

Do you not want to use a fixed height for the list items? If you don't, and if you don't want to use a script, then off the top of my head:

Add a paragraph element in the last li that contains the same copy as the previous list items. Set that paragraph's opacity to 0. Position the button absolutely in the li item and center it using the transform trick:

```
button {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%);
}
```

It's a little messy but I can't think of another way besides using a fixed height or using a script.

Comment: fixed height is out of option, so I would probably need to go with a script

Comment: It's a little cleaner for sure. The method I posted above should work though if you are trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

If you overwrite bootstrap rules with flex, it can easily be done nd you may even align the content of the link: https://jsfiddle.net/fr6gachf/2/

```css
body {
  background-color: #e4e5e7!important;/* ?? wt@ with the code snippet ? */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  ;
}

li div.test-wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 25px
}

li div.test-wrapper a,
li div.test-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

li div.test-wrapper a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="test-wrapper text-center">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo lacus, congue at arcu at, gravida congue orci. Fusce id tempor orci, nec efficitur ex. Mauris vitae nunc dui. Donec dui justo, pulvinar ut congue vitae, tempor porta sem. Q
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="test-wrapper text-center">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo lacus, congue at arcu at, gravida congue orci. Fusce id tempor orci, nec efficitur ex. Mauris vitae nunc dui. Donec dui justo, pulvinar ut congue vitae, tempor porta sem. Q
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="test-wrapper text-center">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo lacus, congue at arcu at, gravida congue orci. Fusce id tempor orci, nec efficitur ex. Mauris vitae nunc dui. Donec dui justo, pulvinar ut congue vitae, tempor porta sem. Q
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="test-wrapper text-center">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo lacus, congue at arcu at, gravida congue orci. Fusce id tempor orci, nec efficitur ex. Mauris vitae nunc dui. Donec dui justo, pulvinar ut congue vitae, tempor porta sem. Q
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="test-wrapper text-center">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo lacus, congue at arcu at, gravida congue orci. Fusce id tempor orci, nec efficitur ex. Mauris vitae nunc dui. Donec dui justo, pulvinar ut congue vitae, tempor porta sem. Q
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="test-wrapper text-center">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo lacus, congue at arcu at, gravida congue orci. Fusce id tempor orci, nec efficitur ex. Mauris vitae nunc dui. Donec dui justo, pulvinar ut congue vitae, tempor porta sem. Q
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="test-wrapper text-center">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo lacus, congue at arcu at, gravida congue orci. Fusce id tempor orci, nec efficitur ex. Mauris vitae nunc dui. Donec dui justo, pulvinar ut congue vitae, tempor porta sem. Q
    </div>
  </li>
  
   <li class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="test-wrapper text-center">
     <a href="#">this is button</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a script to do it. I use jQuery for this, here is the code  :

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $("ul li").map(function ()
{
    return $(this).height();
}).get());

$('.button').css('height', maxHeight-25+"px");
```

The first part get the max height of all li elements and then it set it to the button.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fr6gachf/5/)